# Text not showing up as hyperlink - CSS issue?

Tags: css, xhtml

I can't determine why this text can't be scrolled over and the hyperlink (all in the body of the page) can't be clicked. I'm not sure if it's a CSS issue, or some other kind of issue.

The XHTML is valid, but the CSS isn't totally. Wondering if I can fix without totally remedying every CSS element.

http://www.writershore.com/ltlaw

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The z-index of your `div.main` style is set to -1. Because of this, it is located *under* some other div. Just set it to something higher and everything should be good.

Comment: Ding! I was wondering. Firebug didn't want to even inspect it.

Comment: can't even imagine why the -1 was there - care to enlighten us?

Comment: Yeah, when I could 'inspect element' in FireBug, I knew something must've been covering it.

Comment: I put the -1 there because in any non-IE8 versions of IE, the menu drop downs were getting covered up by the surrounding divs. So it was a workaround for that. changing it to 0 fixed my a href issue, but I'm sure there are plenty of issues to work out with how the page is built, especially as it goes on IE browsers. I'll give this one the credit since it fixed my immediate issue.

Answer (score 1):

First on all, your site doesn't seems to validate 100% of [XHTML](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.writershore.com%2Fltlaw%2F&charset=(detect+automatically)&doctype=Inline&group=0.).

Also, your Web site doesn't work correctly on IE, so you must have something wrong in your XHTML and/or CSS and/or JavaScript.

Now what you can do is to try to remove your reference to all your CSS file and see if it's work. If it's still doesn't work, remove your JavaScript reference and see if it's work.

If fact, at this step, what you want to know is where the error come from, because if I take your "a href" tag and put it in an empty file, it's work, so your XHTML seems right.

My way to resolve this kind of problem is to reduce the problem at is simple expression. By that I mean, remove all the external factor that can have an impact in my problem.

I hope this will help.

Let me know of your result.